# 15 digit number with a letter on the end

Tags: microsoft-excel

I get spreadsheets with 1,000 15 digit numbers with a letter added on the end. I can retain the number by formatting the cells to Text and then remove the letter manually and it's fine. BUT if I use the Find/Replace mode to remove the letter, it converts the 15 digit number to that exponential format (is that what its called?).

Anyone know how I can efficiently replace this letter with 'blank' and retain the 15 digit number?

e.g.

> 123456789012345F

-> I want it to

> 123456789012345

Thank you!

Comment: Do you need the number to be numeric (do calculations with it), or just preserve all 15 digits (can be text)?

Comment: Just need to preserve the 15 digits... will then do a vlookup to bring over another piece of data from another spreadsheet.

Comment: Couldn't duplicate the problem in LibreOffice Calc; just had a chance to replicate it in Excel. The problem is just formatting.  When you highlight the cells for find/replace, format them to a number with zero decimal places after the replace-all.

Comment: If you only want to remove the letter for the purposes of lookup, then just use `LEFT(A2,15)` directly in the lookup formula. Side note: `INDEX`+`MATCH` is more robust and faster than `VLOOKUP`

Answer (score 1):

If you *actually* want to replace the letters with a blank, use the following formula to start a "helper column" and then copy it & "Paste Values Only". Formula assumes your data starts at A2:

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A2,15)," ")
```

If all you want to do is make the number fully display, instead of using the "E" notation, you need to format the cells as a number. Use this for your helper column, copy it and "Paste Values Only", then format the cells as numbers:

```
=LEFT(A2,15)
```

[image]